# Why are these str id's not the same?

Tags: python, string

> **upper() Return Value**
>
> upper() method returns the uppercase string from the given string. It converts all lowercase characters to uppercase.
> If no lowercase characters exist, it returns the original string.

If it is so then why their id's are not same since upper here is returning the original string to y?

```
x = 'PYTHONCORE'
y = x.upper()
print(id(y), id(x))
```

Output:

```
1925088550320 1925088583152
```

Comment: `y` is the address of the *function*.  Print `y` and you’ll see what this means.  Perhaps you mean `x.upper()`?

Comment: Even so, they are different strings (different *objects*), due to assignment. And therefore have different memory addresses.

Comment: yes i just checked that y is returning the address of the function.

Comment: can you give more insight on how they are different strings?

Comment: @ShivaGupta - I’ll be happy to later, but can’t at the minute. In the meantime, this post by Ned B might be extremely useful.  [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: @kwinkunks i know that strings are immutable but since it says it returns original string if no lowercase character is found, i thought it will store the original string in y

Comment: Key: “original string” is *very* different than the original *object*.

Comment: Probably because the claim that it returns the original string comes from geeksforgeeks, which is well-known to be a terrible site?

Comment: @KellyBundy it is actually from programiz

Comment: @ShivaGupta - Regardless, the point is the same.  Often times these sites are incomplete, misleading, oversimplified, or just plain *wrong*.  I’d recommend sticking to the official Python docs.

Comment: Note the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) for `upper` states: “ Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters 4 converted to uppercase.”  **Note:** A *copy* of the string.  Problem solved.

Comment: @S3DEV a copy of the string even if the string is already in uppercase?

Comment: Think of it as a copy of an *object*, regardless of what the object contains.

Answer (score 2):

The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) for the `.upper` method states:

> “Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters converted to uppercase.”

**Note:** A *copy* of the string, therefore different objects with different memory addresses. Problem solved.

Comment: Exactly. If in doubt, the official documentation or `help(str.upper)` is what you check out.